# Format Currency to Group By Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access table with original balances for 200,000 loans and I'd like to group them into buckets of $5,000 increments all the way to $100,000+, like this:

0-5,000

5,001-10,000

10,001-15,000

(and so on)

Of course, I could write the world's longest IIF statement to satisfy those conditions, but there has to be an easier way? I've been using the FORMAT() function to do something similar with the Open Dates, like this:

```
Month: Format([Loans].[OpenDate],"YYYY-MM")
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: where would 5000.01 go?

Comment: It doesn't need to be 5000.01 exactly, just >5000 and <=10000

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Access? Don't spam tags.

Comment: `GROUP BY FLOOR(balance/5000)`

Comment: Very nice barmar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the balance by 5000 and group by the integer portion of this.

```
SELECT ...
GROUP BY INT(balance/5000)
```

Comment: To answer your first question, MS Access. I removed the sql tag, that was a mistake. GROUP BY FLOOR is not a function in Access, unfortunately.

Comment: Apparently Access calls it `INT()`.

Comment: Took me a minute to figure it out but I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create an inline view with the ranges and join to it...

I cant remember if msAccess supports select without a from or if it has a dual like oracle.... but there has to be a way.... similar to this...

```
SELECT A.*, B.Range 
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 0 as Low, 5000 as High, '0-5000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 5000 as Low, 10000 as High, '5000-10000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 10000 as Low, 15000 as High, '10000-15000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 15000 as Low, 20000 as High, '15000-20000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 20000 as Low, 25000 as High, '20000-25000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 25000 as Low, 30000 as High, '25000-30000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 30000 as Low, 35000 as High, '30000-35000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 35000 as Low, 40000 as High, '35000-40000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 40000 as Low, 45000 as High, '40000-45000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 45000 as Low, 50000 as High, '45000-50000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 50000 as Low, 55000 as High, '50000-55000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 55000 as Low, 60000 as High, '55000-60000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 60000 as Low, 65000 as High, '60000-65000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 65000 as Low, 70000 as High, '65000-70000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 70000 as Low, 75000 as High, '70000-75000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 75000 as Low, 80000 as High, '75000-80000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 80000 as Low, 85000 as High, '80000-85000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 85000 as Low, 90000 as High, '85000-90000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 90000 as Low, 95000 as High, '90000-95000' as Range UNION ALL 
SELECT 95000 as Low, 100000 as High, '95000-100000' as Range 
) B
 on A.Balance > B.Low 
and A.Balance <= B.High
```